# Checking for automating water topoff

Tags: c++, arduino

The purpose of this code to is check the 3 float switches in the laminator chamber for water. The float switches vote with the majority winning. A momentary switch must be pressed for the section of code (`//// START FILL LAMINATOR FROM 70GALLON RES ///`) to be active.

We can also take water from the reservoir using a different button (latching):

```
///// START Fill Water Bucket

///START set pins  ///
const int startBucket =5;
const int pumpBucketValve =6;
const int startButton = 7;
const int floatSwitch1 = 8;
const int floatSwitch2 = 9;
const int floatSwitch3 = 10;
const int pumpPower = 11;
const int pumpBallValve = 12;
///END set pins  ///


///START set pins values  ///
int floatSwitchState1 = 0;
int floatSwitchState2 = 0;
int floatSwitchState3 = 0;
int summedValue = 0;
int pumpPowerState = 0; //turns pump on and opens the ball valve to the laminator
int startButtonState = 0;
int startBucketState = 0;
int pumpBucketValveState = 0;

///END set pins values  ///


///START set pins mode  ///
void setup() {

pinMode(floatSwitch1, INPUT);
pinMode(floatSwitch2, INPUT);
pinMode(floatSwitch3, INPUT);
pinMode(pumpPower, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pumpBucketValve, OUTPUT);
pinMode(startButton, INPUT);
pinMode(startBucket, INPUT);
}

///END set pins modes  ///

void loop() {
//// START FILL LAMINATOR FROM 70GALLON RES ///
startButtonState = digitalRead(startButton);
if (startButtonState == HIGH) {
    while (checkFloat >= 2) {
      digitalWrite(pumpPower, HIGH);
    }
      digitalWrite(pumpPower, LOW);
}
//// END FILL LAMINATOR FROM 70GALLON RES ///


///// START Fill Water Bucket
startBucketState = digitalRead(startBucket);
while (startButtonState == HIGH) {
      digitalWrite(pumpBucketValve, HIGH); //turn ball valve to on
    }

digitalWrite(pumpBucketValve, LOW); //turn ball valve to off

///// END FILL Water Bucket
}

int checkFloat() {
    summedValue = 0;
    floatSwitchState1 = digitalRead(floatSwitch1);
    if (floatSwitchState1 == HIGH) {
      summedValue = summedValue + 1;
    }
    floatSwitchState2 = digitalRead(floatSwitch2);
    if (floatSwitchState2 == HIGH) {
      summedValue = summedValue + 1;
    }
    floatSwitchState3 = digitalRead(floatSwitch2);
    if (floatSwitchState3 == HIGH) {
      summedValue = summedValue + 1;
    }
    return summedValue;
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? Skimming through the code gives me doubts that it's been tested..

Comment: Did you notice that this is Arduino code and it compiles with a different library and a bunch of preprocessing?

Comment: Concerns: Is `while (checkFloat >= 2)` valid?  Arduino's docs do not mention a change in [function call syntax](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FunctionDeclaration).  Does `startButtonState` get asynchronously updated or is there an endless loop that doesn't stop the filling process once it begins?

Comment: Those do look like real issues. However, I was making sure you didn't completely skim the question, since there was an answer below (now removed) that had things to the effect of "you should rename the loop function".

Comment: I suggest that you fix your syntax error in your while conditional.   `while (checkFloat >= 2) {`  this doesn't work.

Comment: if you fix your syntax error we can reopen this question and I am sure that you will get more answers that will help you write better, cleaner code

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of comments that are completely unnecessary, they are not needed.

```
int pumpPowerState = 0; //turns pump on and opens the ball valve to the laminator
```

The name of the variable tells me what this is and what it needs to do.  `pumpPowerState` that tells me the pump is either off or on and the assignment tells me we are using a `0` or a `1` to determine the on/off state of the device being controlled.

also the comments before and after the blocks are rather redundant as well, most of your blocks of code that you comment before and after are obvious what they are

> ```
> ///START set pins mode  ///
> ```

then there is your comment before the code inside the loop.

> ```
> //// START FILL LAMINATOR FROM 70GALLON RES ///
> ```

This tells me that you should have a function that you call inside the loop, something like this

```
void FillLaminator() {
    startButtonState = digitalRead(startButton);
    if (startButtonState == HIGH) {
        while (checkFloat() >= 2) {
            digitalWrite(pumpPower, HIGH);
        }
    }
    digitalWrite(pumpPower, LOW);
}
```

And while we are at it:

```
void FillWaterBucket() {
    startBucketState = digitalRead(startBucket);
    while (startButtonState == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(pumpBucketValve, HIGH); //turn ball valve to on
    }
    digitalWrite(pumpBucketValve, LOW); //turn ball valve to off
}
```

Then you call it like this inside of the loop

```
void loop() {
    FillLaminator();
    FillWaterBucket();
}
```

---

Please indent the code inside of brackets so that you can tell the scope more easily.

Do this:

```
void setup() {

    pinMode(floatSwitch1, INPUT);
    pinMode(floatSwitch2, INPUT);
    pinMode(floatSwitch3, INPUT);
    pinMode(pumpPower, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pumpBucketValve, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(startButton, INPUT);
    pinMode(startBucket, INPUT);
}
```

instead of this:

> ```
> void setup() {
>
> pinMode(floatSwitch1, INPUT);
> pinMode(floatSwitch2, INPUT);
> pinMode(floatSwitch3, INPUT);
> pinMode(pumpPower, OUTPUT);
> pinMode(pumpBucketValve, OUTPUT);
> pinMode(startButton, INPUT);
> pinMode(startBucket, INPUT);
> }
> ```

that should be a good start to writing cleaner Arduino code.